# check the convergence of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Help me on checking the convergence of the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx$$
I have tried it in this way $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx+\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx+\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx$$and then by taking comparison integral $\frac{1}{1-x}$, I came into conclusion that $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{x\log x}\,dx$ is divergent, then I thought the given integral must be divergent, but when I saw it's answer it's given that it is convergent. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: compute $\ln(\ln(x))'$

Comment: I was thinking that can the sum of two divergent improper integrals be convergent.

Comment: Not usually. Except if you use things like the [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) (not here). Btw the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) may interest you too for [generalizations](http://imperator.usc.edu/~bruck/classes/fall2009/math425a/Cauchy_condensation.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integral convergent test says that $$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log x}$$ converges if and only if this sum converges: $$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$$
Use Cauchy condensation test we can see this sum does not converge. Your suggested answer is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\int\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\log(|\log x|)+C\to\infty\quad\text{when}\quad x\to\infty \quad\text{or}\quad x\to0$$
so for $a>0$ the both integrals
$$\int_0^a\frac{dx}{x\log x}\quad;\quad \int_a^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log x}$$
are divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $u=\log x$. And compare with the convergence of $$\int\frac{1}{u} \,du$$

Comment: This is the definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} du/u$, and the PRINCIPAL VALUE integral presumably exists and is zero for this.  But we should explain what we mean, since it is improper both at $0$ and at $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution $u=\log x, du=\frac{1}{x} dx$, we find the antiderivative $\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}$ to the indefinite integral.    To find the definite integral, we split it into $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x\log x} dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\log x} dx$, replace the improper endpoints ($0, \infty$) with constants, use the antiderivative above, then take limits as those constants approach $0,\infty$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong and the book is right (no offence). Make the substition u=-log(x) into vadim's first integral $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x \log(x)}dx$ add it to vadim's second integral and you will see that it converges.